# Manipulate array referenced from a list - R

Tags: r, arrays, list, data-manipulation

How can I manipulate arrays referenced using the names in a list?

For instance how would I add a new column and assign a value to arrays `a` and `b` by referencing them from a list? as shown in this example:

```
a = data.frame(v1 = seq(1,5), v2=seq(1,5))
b = data.frame(v1 = seq(2,5), v2=seq(2,5))

list = c("a", "b")

for(i in list){
  # print array
  print(get(i))

  # or create copy and assign value
  j=get(i)
  j$v3 = 1
}
```

Comment: Use can access specific items in a list by bracketing.  Here is a brief tutorial: https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-extract-components-from-lists-in-r/

Comment: hi, thanks but I believe that would only allow me to reference the characters `"a"` or `"b"` and not the underlying arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dont use functions (like list) as variable names. Thats really a no-no.
If you want to save a and b in a list you need to do this:

```
 your_list <- list("a" = a,
                   "b" = b)
```

You want to loop over the names of the list

```
for(i in names(list)){
   # print array
   print(your_list[[i]]) # you need two [ when referencing on a list

   # or create copy and assign value
   j <- your_list[[i]]
   j$v3 <- seq(1:nrow(j))
   assign(i,j)
}
```

Comment: thanks, I would not have choosen it to work this way, but an external function `getSymbols()` creates a set of `xts` objects with the names of the stocks that you pass too it. Hence I have a list of array objects but only their character names and they are not linked to the underlying objects.

Comment: So you have variables a,b,... and a list, that only contains "a","b",... but no linking to the actual variables, do i get that right? If so, try assign (i,j) at the end of the loop